# Is there a way to stop buildozer from cloning python-for-android?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

Everytime I make an app, buildozer always tries to clone  python-for-android from github.

Is it really necessary to clone everytime I make my app? And is there another way aside from cloning python-for-android everytime I make my app?

see image

[image]

I don't have much internet connection and I'm just making a simple app like hello world .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clone python-for-android somewhere manually
2. Install dependencies your cloned version would need (can be done just installing python-for-android with pip)
3. Change your `buildozer.spec` file adding option `p4a.source_dir`
   pointing to cloned directory (for example `p4a.source_dir =
   /home/ken/python-for-android`)

Done! Now buildozer will use your local python-for-android.